# Как вызвать исполняемый файл в окне пользователя посредством pypsexec?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для примера пытаюсь вызвать notepad.exe в окне пользователя, но ничего не происходит. Код который я использую:

```
from pypsexec.client import Client

c = Client("127.0.0.1", username="username", password="password", encrypt=False)
c.connect()
c.create_service()
c.run_executable("cmd.exe", arguments=r"/c start C:\Windows\notepad.exe")
c.remove_service()
c.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо указать: interactive=True